# i want to use for-each on my code igniter but i am using conditione of (id) and my other conditione

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

on the view i want to use foreach but with the condition of the **id** i get from mypost

**model**

```
public function get_rows($id= FALSE)
        {
            if ($id === FALSE)
            {
            $query = $this->db->get('table1');
            return $query->result_array();
            $config['per_page'];
                   $this->uri->segment(3);
            }
        $query = $this->db->get_where('table1', array('id'=> $id,'type'=> 2));
            return $query->row_array();
          }
```

**Controller**

```
 public function index($id){    
        $data['rows'] = $this->model->get_rows($id);
        if (empty($data['rows']))
        {
        show_404();
        }
        $data['id'] = $data['rows']['id'];
        $this->load->view('view', $data);

    }
```

**View**

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $row):  ?>
    <li><?php echo $row->title; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Here i want to use for each on my view but with the condition of(**ID**) i get from the post and the **type** i set my self

thanks in advance...
rafiq__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In view use `$row['title'];` not `$row->title;`

**View**

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $row):  ?>
    <li><?php echo $row['title']; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and may be you need to change `return $query->row_array();` to `return $query->result_array();` in your model.

**Model**

```
public function get_rows($id = 0){

    if ($id > 0){
         $this->db->where(array('id'=> $id,'type'=> 2));
    }

    return $this->db->get('table1')->result_array();
}
```

Comment: it listing all my rows doest get the condition 
codition is like::
**id** get but **type** i set my selef

still listing all the rows